# MEANJS boilerplate : where to include custom javascript files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I started using the Mean JS boilerplate ([ref website](http://meanjs.org)) and would like to know where the recommended place to include public custom javascript, jQuery files (ex. FacebookSDK, jQuery animations,...) .

I'm assuming it's going to be somewhere in the public folder. The default structure is as follows : [image]

Should it go in modules or lib folder? Can you give more guidelines on what the function of each folder is? Any guidelines?

Comment: Have you found a better answer?

Comment: I needed to research it more. I definately like your folder structure. The only issue is that the MeanJS Boilerplate has a much more granular structure. Each module (or component in your structure) has its own routes file, config file and even css/ and img/ folder. I can't get my head around this logic, but it's probably worth opening another question

Comment: Oh yeah, I've tried both MeanJS and MeanIO, and just like other projects I download with Yoeman, I eventually remove most of what's there and make my own structure. Eventually maybe I'll post my own Yoeman build, so I download what I like working with, gulp setup the way I like it, SASS files and an Angular app starter :) I find its best to work with what you feels is the best in the end. Keeps things light too...

Comment: @StephLhm I am looking to know the exact same thing, what did you settle with? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great article on Angular app folder structure:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

To answer your question about stuff like jQuery / bootstrap.js I would put them into a libs folder.

I use this methodology in all my apps now. For your Angular files the old way / way for small apps would probably have been this:

```
app/
----- controllers/
---------- mainController.js
---------- otherController.js
----- directives/
---------- mainDirective.js
---------- otherDirective.js
----- services/
---------- userService.js
---------- itemService.js
----- js/
---------- bootstrap.js
---------- jquery.js
----- app.js
views/
----- mainView.html
----- otherView.html
----- index.html
```

Better more efficient way (more descriptive as well):

```
app/
----- shared/   // acts as reusable components or partials of our site
---------- sidebar/
--------------- sidebarDirective.js
--------------- sidebarView.html
---------- article/
--------------- articleDirective.js
--------------- articleView.html
----- components/   // each component is treated as a mini Angular app
---------- home/
--------------- homeController.js
--------------- homeService.js
--------------- homeView.html
---------- blog/
--------------- blogController.js
--------------- blogService.js
--------------- blogView.html
----- app.module.js
----- app.routes.js
assets/
----- img/      // Images and icons for your app
----- css/      // All styles and style related files (SCSS or LESS files)
----- js/       // JavaScript files written for your app that are not for angular
----- libs/     // Third-party libraries such as jQuery, Moment, Underscore, etc.
index.html
```

What I'm using in my current project:
[image]